# MongoDB, I want to update all arrays inside nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I want to add "3" to all "seenBy" array which is inside "Conversation" array.

```
{
  _id : 1,
  name : "name",
  email : "email",
  conversation : [
      {
        message : "Hai",
        seenBy : [1,2]
      },
      {
        message : "Hai",
        seenBy : [1,2]
      },
      {
        message : "Hai",
        seenBy : [1,2]
      }
  ]
}
```

Expected result :

```
{
  name : "name",
  email : "email",
  conversation : [
      {
        message : "Hai",
        seenBy : [1,2,3]
      },
      {
        message : "Hai",
        seenBy : [1,2,3]
      },
      {
        message : "Hai",
        seenBy : [1,2,3]
      }
  ]
}
```

My code :

```
DB.Users.update({_id : 1}, {$addToSet : {"conversation.$[].seenBy" : 3}}, {}, function(err, result){
console.log(err);
console.log(result)
})
```

I get this error :

MongoError: cannot use the part (conversation of conversation.$[].seenBy) to traverse the element

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying `_id` field in the data set u mentioned:

```
{
  name : "name",
  email : "email",
  conversation : [
  {
    message : "Hai",
    seenBy : [1,2]
  },
  {
    message : "Hai",
    seenBy : [1,2]
  },
  {
    message : "Hai",
    seenBy : [1,2]
  }
 ]
}
```

So, MongoDB add an `ObjectID` automatically, so you need to specify that. `_id:1` will work if u have the specified `_id` in the DB. I'm getting proper output using your above query:
[image]
[image]

So, the issue is with your mongoose code and not with the Mongo query.

Comment: thomas get truw answer and run away:D

Comment: Sorry. Check my "Update" query. I am using "_id" to update the document.

Comment: Not funny :P @ŞükranEken

Comment: I am using mongoose and i don't know why its throwing error. @Rahul Raj

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can access nested array in document and push in it

Something like

```
db.Users.update(
{},
{ "$push": {"conversation.$[].seenBy": 3}}
)
```

Note. This will add `3` to all of your documents. You can add any filter based on your requirements